# VB.net call a dll after decode from base64 string and load them

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to call a `dll` after decode from base64 string and load them.
However, I don't have any idea how to complete this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Reflection.Assembly.Load(crypt())

End Sub

Public Function crypt() As Byte()

    Return XORDcrypt(Convert.FromBase64String("Base64 String "), "david")

End Function
```

original call of dll

```
= ClassLibrary1.A.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this, to call the `main` method using reflection.

```
Imports System.Reflection

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Load the assembly
    Dim assm As Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.Load(crypt())
    ' Get the type description for the ClassLibrary1.A class
    Dim objType As Type = assm.GetType("ClassLibrary1.A")
    ' Create an instance of ClassLibrary1.A, using the default constructor
    Dim obj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(objType)
    ' Get the method info for the "main" method with no parameters
    Dim methInfo As MethodInfo = objType.GetMethod("main")
    ' Call the main method
    methInfo.Invoke(obj, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Comment: @DavidP.Swanson did you get an error?  what does your code look like now?

Comment: How to do for write code like this
what is the basic??

Comment: @DavidP.Swanson I've commented the code to show how it works a little better.